# dontRollbackOn for StatelessSessionBean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb-3.0

With Transactional CDI beans I can configure [dont]rollbackOn behaviour on method level:

```
@Transactional(**dontRollbackOn** = {}, rollbackOn = {})
public void transactionalMethod()...
```

How can I configure it on method level for

```
@Steteless 
public class SessionBean {...} ?
```

Is it possible ?

I know I can annotate exceptions with

```
 @AppliationException(rollback=false)
```

but I would like to have configuration over method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible in current versions of EJB.  Your only options are to use pure CDI rather than EJB, or to use bean-managed transactions and manage the rollback yourself.

There is an open issue against the EJB spec: [@ApplicationException to allow finer grain control](https://java.net/jira/browse/EJB_SPEC-88)